# Angular 4 constructor value used on *ngIf

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

In the following typescript code I have a value `moreinfo` which I initialize to 1. After that inside the constructor I change the value to 2. So with value 1 I display one `div` with `*ngIf` and with value 2 I display a different `div`. All works perfectly and I see that the value has correctly changed to 2 from console.

```js
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  moreinfo: number=1;
  email: string;
  password: string;

  constructor(public afAuth: AngularFireAuth, public af: 
    AngularFireDatabase,public authService: AuthService) {

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
      if (user) {
        this.moreinfo=2;
        var user2 = firebase.auth().currentUser;
        console.log("Current user id:" + user2.uid + "\nMoreinfo:" + this.moreinfo);
      } else {
        console.log("No user is signed in."); 
      }
    });
  }
}
```

However when I compare the value in the HTML it displays the `div` with `morevalue == 1;` despite the fact that the value has changed to 2. Is there anyone that can shed some light on my problem?

```html
<div class="container" *ngIf="moreinfo == 1">
  <h1 *ngIf="authService.user | async">Welcome {{ (authService.user | async)?.email }}!</h1>
</div>

<div class="container" *ngIf="moreinfo == 2">
  something
</div>
```

Comment: However when I complare the value ?

Comment: You said that you change the value to 2.  But I don't see that anywhere.  It looks like you initialize it to 1 and you also set it to 1 in the constructor.  Is this right?

Comment: When I use the value moreinfo on *ngIf it always show the div with ngIf="moreinfo==1" and the value has changed to 2. Is there any way I can control it?

Comment: @Zekelonas check my answer, it explains what is happening.

Comment: Yes sorry while I was testing the code I forgot to change the value to 2. I edited my post now

Comment: So you now explicitly set it to 2 when you have a user, but still get the scenario with no user. Are you sure that user exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because the closure that you are using is incorrect, instead of an anonymous function, try an arrow function, which should set the value in the component - not just in the function.

Like this:

```js
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if (user) {
    this.moreinfo=2;
    var user2 = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    console.log("Current user id:" + user2.uid + "\nMoreinfo:" + this.moreinfo);
  } else {
    console.log("No user is signed in."); 
  }
});
```

Comment: Wow that worked! Thanks you very much.. so the problem was that the value moreinfo was only changed localy inside the function and outside was still 1??

Comment: exactly! if you'd tested it with `console.log()` outside of that function it would have still been 1

Comment: Ah nice.. thanks you so much for the help :)